# Emulator hangs with Task status WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, task

I am trying to fetch data from an API.

When I write all code in one method like as follows it work fine.

```
private async void btvalidate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("mybaseaddress");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("mylocaluri");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)// check whether response status is true
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();//read the data in the response
                var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myclassname>(data.Result.ToString());//convert the string response in json format
                validate.DataContext = msg;// assign the data received to stackpanel  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Somethimng went wrong" + ex);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to write this code in a method of a separate class and call it from a click event as follows, it hangs on click of event and has status of data as WaitingforActivation...

```
public class API
{
    public async Task<string> getAPI(string uri)
    {
        string data1 = null;
        var data=data1;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("mybaseaddress");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)// check whether response status is true
                {
                    data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;//read the data in the response
                }
           }
        return data;
    } 
}

private void btcount_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = api.getAPI("mylocaluri");
        var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myclassname>(data.Result.ToString());//convert the string response in json format
        validate.DataContext = msg;// assign the data received to stackpanel
    }
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Stop using `.Result` either use `await` everywhere or switch to `WebClient` and make the functions non-async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're [causing a deadlock by calling `Result`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), which I explain in full on my blog.

The best solution is to [use `async` "all the way"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), as I describe in my MSDN article on `async` best practices.

In this particular case, replace `Result` with `await`:

```
private async void btcount_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var data = await api.getAPI("mylocaluri");
  var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myclassname>(data.ToString());//convert the string response in json format
  validate.DataContext = msg;// assign the data received to stackpanel
}
```

On a side note, consider renaming `getAPI` to `GetApiAsync`, to follow [common naming patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx).